# Postgres SQL - Join data from 3 table to select one column

Tags: postgresql

I have 3 tables with the following schema

```
Table1 - plan
id | count

Table2 - subscription
id | plan_id

Table3 - users
id | subscription_id
```

I have to select count from plans where its plan.id matches with subscription.plan_id matches and users.subscription_id matches with subscription.id and users.id = '5'

How can I use a JOIN here?

I tried using with no JOIN as below:

```
SELECT count 
    FROM users, subscription, plan 
    WHERE users.id = '5' and users.subscription_id = subscription.id and subscription.plan_id = plan.id;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to avoid `implicit` sql joins rather use `explicit` joins (`e.g. inner join,left join..`) in order to retain readability.

A cleaner way would be the following:

```
SELECT
    count
FROM
    users
INNER JOIN  subscription ON users.subscription_id = subscription.id
INNER JOIN  plan ON subscription.plan_id = plan.id
WHERE   users.id = '5'
```

---

<kbd>[**Explicit vs implicit SQL joins**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917/explicit-vs-implicit-sql-joins)</kbd>

Comment: You mean from `FROM plan`?

Comment: yes. `...FROM table1,table2,table3...,tableN..` is another form of `CROSS JOIN` among those tables.